# How to implement Math.round to achieve 3dp output?

Tags: java

```
public class Favorite {

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {

    String itemName = "Golden Beans";
    double offerPrice = 314;
    int sellPrice = 321;
    double value = (sellPrice - offerPrice);
    int cashStack = 500_000;
    double percentageProfit = ((value / offerPrice) * 100);


    System.out.println("Approx. Offer Price is " + offerPrice);
    System.out.println("Approx. Sell Price is " + sellPrice);
    System.out.println("The potential profit margin is " + value);
    System.out.println("With a cash stack of " + cashStack + " we can buy " + cashStack / offerPrice + " " + itemName +"s");
    System.out.println("The profit margin of " + itemName + " as a percentage is " + percentageProfit);

    }
}
```

- make a mini program that I determine buy and sell price for and it tells me the profit margin. DONE
- then find out how many of the item I can purchase for 500,000. DONE
- then make it more advanced by getting the program to tell me what the profit is of the buy price. DONE
- then have the program output to 3 decimal places. (This is where I'm stuck!)

Comment: you can't round (some numbers) to 3dp, a `double` has a limited precision and would need to be adjusted more than just rounding, e.g. `0.11111` could need to become `0.110` because `0.111` can't be represented. (Not sure if valid example but it illustrates the problem)

Comment: Basic rule you should learn early: do not use floats or doubles to represent money. When adding them up, you may lose money because decimal fractions can't always be represented in binary.  Either work with integers in a scale of 1000, or use a class that represents the money exactly, like `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into BigDecimal a little further down the line, I'm a new learner at the moment but I can appreciate its usefulness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation first - [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html):

```
System.out.printf("%.3f", res);
```

or [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
System.out.println(new java.text.DecimalFormat("#.000").format(500.12321313));
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly when I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try `printf()` instead of `println()` use format `%.3f`:

```
System.out.printf("The profit margin of %s as a percentage is %.3f%n" itemName,percentageProfit);
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for DecimalFormat
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

That class is able to do a lot of work with formatting numbers, from changing the separators to automatically round up the numbers the way you desire.

Try to instantiate one of these, then configure it, and play a bit with the options until you understand how it works, and finally just call its "format" method on whatever number you want to transform to a String.